# @implicit Lang not working in template after upgrading to play 2.1.0

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

This was working for me in play 2.0.2, but after upgrading to 2.1.0 I get all my strings in the default language:

```
@(licenseRequestForm: Form[LicenseRequest], generatedLicense: nl.avisi.langur.license.License, lang: String)
@implicitLang = @{ new Lang(lang) }

<h2>@Messages("license.form.title")</h2>
```

Any idea why the implicitLang is not being picked up in version 2.1.0?

Comment: Are you using Scala or Java?

Comment: The Controller is Java. The method using the (scala) template above is:
  `public static Result license(String lang) {
    return ok(license.render(licenseRequestForm, null, lang));
  }`

Comment: I tried passing a Lang instead of a String from the Controller to the template `(implicit lang: Lang)`. But apparently passing implicits from Java to the Scala template is not that easy. Exactly that is the reason for the workaround, that worked up until version 2.0.2, but not for 2.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a regression.

The only temporary workaround would be to pass the lang explicitly to Messages, i.e. `<h2>@Messages("license.form.title")(implicitLang)</h2>`.

Comment: I followed that guide precisely and did not forget to add javaCore:
    `val appDependencies = Seq(
        javaCore, "org.apache.commons" % "commons-email" % "1.2"
    )`

Comment: Ok I see, I edited accordingly, but there doesn't seem to be a real solution then...

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Really appreciated. I will try the user group and if that doesn't work out, I will file a bug in Lighthouse.